# Traverse a complex array of nested arrays using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need some new idea's, I have tried different approach's using foreach statement along with Iteratorts in PHP5. I am currently parsing a response from UPS for a multi package rate response.

The API returns all of its service offerings, Ground, Next day air etc.  I want to focus in the Key Service which is an array that holds the 'Code' value. Once it find's the correct service value, is when I  want to pull the Array RatedPackages then traverse it for the different services and its costs of each package.

I have tried the following code but no avail, i would rather see different approaches, i am not a master when it comes to parsing arrays.  Is is better to send the array to a different structure such as json etc.  I have no idea.

Solution Expected is When 'Service array member Code - 01 is when i need to pull the Rated Packages array so i can produce the Shipping Label.

If anyone has a better aproach I am open to all and any suggestions, if i was not clear ask me a question and i will respond the best of my ability.

thank you in advance

Anyway here is my code:

```
try {
    $object = new ArrayIterator( $arr );
    $object->rewind();

    while( $object->valid()){
        echo $object->key(). "-&gt; ". $object->current()."<br>";
        if(is_array($object->current())) {
            foreach($object->current() as $node => $value) {
                //echo "item: ".$item. " value: ".$value. "<br>";
               if($node == 'Service') {

                    if(is_array($value)) {
                        s($value->code);

                        foreach($value as $item => $v){
                            echo "item: ".$item. " value: ".$v. "<br>";
                            if($v == '01'){
                                echo "HIT OUR MARK!!!!!!!";

                                $rp = $node[0]['RatedPackage'];
                                s("RP: ".$node);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $object->next();
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

OUTPUT from Code

```
    0-> Array

NULL

item: Code value: 03
1-> Array

NULL

item: Code value: 12
2-> Array

NULL

item: Code value: 02
3-> Array

NULL

item: Code value: 13
4-> Array

NULL

item: Code value: 14
5-> Array

NULL

item: Code value: 01
HIT OUR MARK!!!!!!!
Warning: Illegal string offset 'RatedPackage' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pkdev/dev/portal/shipping.php on line 93

string (11) "RP: Service"

![Snapshot of Array Response][1]


   ARRAY to Parse
    array(1) [
    'RatingServiceSelectionResponse' => array(2) [
        'Response' => array(3) [
            'TransactionReference' => array(1) [
                'CustomerContext' => string (12) "RocketShipIt"
            ]
            'ResponseStatusCode' => string (1) "1"
            'ResponseStatusDescription' => string (7) "Success"
        ]
        'RatedShipment' => array(6) [
            array(9) [
                'Service' => array(1) [
                    'Code' => string (2) "03"
                ]
                'RatedShipmentWarning' => string (56) "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
                'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                    'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                        'Code' => string (3) "LBS"
                    ]
                    'Weight' => string (4) "35.0"
                ]
                'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "37.12"
                ]
                'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                ]
                'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "37.12"
                ]
                'GuaranteedDaysToDelivery' => string (0) ""
                'ScheduledDeliveryTime' => string (0) ""
                'RatedPackage' => array(3) [
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "10.91"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "10.91"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "12.24"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "12.24"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "13.97"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "13.97"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            array(9) [
                'Service' => array(1) [
                    'Code' => string (2) "12"
                ]
                'RatedShipmentWarning' => string (56) "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
                'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                    'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                        'Code' => string (3) "LBS"
                    ]
                    'Weight' => string (4) "35.0"
                ]
                'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "59.57"
                ]
                'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                ]
                'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "59.57"
                ]
                'GuaranteedDaysToDelivery' => string (1) "3"
                'ScheduledDeliveryTime' => string (0) ""
                'RatedPackage' => array(3) [
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "15.29"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "15.29"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "18.59"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "18.59"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "25.69"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "25.69"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            array(9) [
                'Service' => array(1) [
                    'Code' => string (2) "02"
                ]
                'RatedShipmentWarning' => string (56) "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
                'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                    'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                        'Code' => string (3) "LBS"
                    ]
                    'Weight' => string (4) "35.0"
                ]
                'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "77.78"
                ]
                'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                ]
                'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "77.78"
                ]
                'GuaranteedDaysToDelivery' => string (1) "2"
                'ScheduledDeliveryTime' => string (0) ""
                'RatedPackage' => array(3) [
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "19.86"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "19.86"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "23.87"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "23.87"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "34.05"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "34.05"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            array(9) [
                'Service' => array(1) [
                    'Code' => string (2) "13"
                ]
                'RatedShipmentWarning' => string (56) "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
                'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                    'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                        'Code' => string (3) "LBS"
                    ]
                    'Weight' => string (4) "35.0"
                ]
                'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (6) "121.50"
                ]
                'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                ]
                'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (6) "121.50"
                ]
                'GuaranteedDaysToDelivery' => string (1) "1"
                'ScheduledDeliveryTime' => string (0) ""
                'RatedPackage' => array(3) [
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "32.29"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "32.29"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "37.95"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "37.95"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "51.26"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "51.26"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
             array(9) [
                'Service' => array(1) [
                    'Code' => string (2) "01"
                ]
                'RatedShipmentWarning' => string (56) "Your invoice may vary from the displayed reference rates"
                'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                    'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                        'Code' => string (3) "LBS"
                    ]
                    'Weight' => string (4) "35.0"
                ]
                'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (6) "139.05"
                ]
                'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                ]
                'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                    'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                    'MonetaryValue' => string (6) "139.05"
                ]
                'GuaranteedDaysToDelivery' => string (1) "1"
                'ScheduledDeliveryTime' => string (10) "10:30 A.M."
                'RatedPackage' => array(3) [
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "37.02"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "37.02"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (3) "5.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "43.18"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "43.18"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "10.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                    array(5) [
                        'TransportationCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "58.85"
                        ]
                        'ServiceOptionsCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (4) "0.00"
                        ]
                        'TotalCharges' => array(2) [
                            'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
                            'MonetaryValue' => string (5) "58.85"
                        ]
                        'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        'BillingWeight' => array(2) [
                            'UnitOfMeasurement' => array(1) [
                                *depth too great*
                            ]
                            'Weight' => string (4) "20.0"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Hi, is the input data coming as XML string? If yes , can you paste the raw XML in http://pastebin.com This way I will be able to help you with nice and elegant solution.

Comment: No the data is actually coming from an API Library from Rocketshipit who is actually calling the UPS Rate API.

Comment: Here is a nice format of the Complex Array http://pastebin.com/index/a9Hv3Qb5

Comment: OK if it is not CML, then it is JSON format, right? Can you paste the raw data that you are obtaining from the API, so I can demnostrate a working solution with real life data?